# Twenty Ten theme - how to put a different header banner on every page

Tags: themes

1. In the Appearance Menu, submenu ‘Themes’ I prepared several custom banners which remain as menu choices if I do not want them any more. How can I erase them?
2. After searching for answers I found a site http://yoast.com/wordpress-theme-anatomy/ that explained the inner content of a wordpress page. In what they call the ‘cheat-sheet’ for ‘my’ blog’ the header section is referred to as the header-php.
3. In the FTP directory found on the godaddy server I found a listing showing among others file wp-blog-header.php. However, when I click on it the only thing that happens is for the square to the left to be marked. I assume it is within this file that I have to modify the HTML code so as to make the headers on each page independent (?)

Anybody could direct me as to what to do next? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. find and delete the custom header images under ***dashboard -> media -> library***
2. that is referring to header.php in the folder /wp-content/themes/twentyten/
3. don't edit wp-blog-header.php (this is a core file which should never be edited) nor header.php of your theme; simply set a 'featured image' for each page where you want a different header image; the image needs to have a minimum width of 940px.